# Windows 7 Ultimate: language version differences

Tags: windows-7, language, language-pack

Is there any difference between different language versions of Windows 7 Ultimate? If I understand correctly, regardless of whatever language version I'll buy, I can change language after installation.

So my conclusion is that the different language versions are just DVDs preloaded with a specific language pack. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that correct, although the install routines clearly must be slightly different.

There is an underlying language-neutral OS, and then the Language Pack is installed on top of that. This can be seen clearly by the diagrams in the following Microsoft developer's link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/ee461121

This link also has a very nice description of the install differences between English and Chinese:

> "the only difference is only in a different language pack installation
> files for English version of Windows 7, the first installation is
> x86_Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package_6.1.7600. 16385 base package,
> then install x86_Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package_
> 6.1.7600.16385_en-US language pack
>
> For the Chinese version of
> Windows 7, the first installation is
> x86_Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package_6.1.7600. 16385 base package,
> then install x86_Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package_
> 6.1.7600.16385_zh-CN language pack"

http://www.wduu.info/archives/6754.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingual_User_Interface

Comment: So one thing that might be different is that the "language of the first installation" is used for things like default account names, system folder names. Other than that, installation will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct, it is the standard pre-loaded language for the software, you can download new langauge packs or just change it from within the pre-loaded menu